# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We are running Kafka (vesion kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0) in a 2 node cluster.
We have 2 producers (Java API) acting on different topics. Each topic has single partition.
The topic where we had this issue, has one consumer running. 
This set up has been running fine for 3 months, and we saw this issue. All the suggested cases/solutions for this issue in other forums don't seem to apply for my scenario.

Exception at producer;

> -2017-11-25T17:40:33,035 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] ERROR client.producer.BingLogProducerCallback - Encountered exception
>   in sending message ; > org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This
>   server is not the leader for that topic-partition.

We haven't enabled retries for the messages, because this is transactional data and we want to maintain the order.

Producer config:

```
bootstrap.servers : server1ip:9092
acks :all
retries : 0
linger.ms :0
buffer.memory :10240000
max.request.size :1024000
key.serializer : org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
value.serializer : org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

We are connecting to server1 at both producer and consumer. 
The controller log at server2 indicates there is some shutdown happened at during sametime, but I dont understand why this happened.

> [2017-11-25 17:31:44,776] DEBUG [Controller 2]: topics not in
>   preferred replica Map() (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2017-11-25
>   17:31:44,776] TRACE [Controller 2]: leader imbalance ratio for broker
>   2 is 0.000000 (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2017-11-25
>   17:31:44,776] DEBUG [Controller 2]: topics not in preferred replica
>   Map() (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2017-11-25 17:31:44,776]
>   TRACE [Controller 2]: leader imbalance ratio for broker 1 is 0.000000
>   (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2017-11-25 17:34:18,314] INFO
>   [SessionExpirationListener on 2], ZK expired; shut down all controller
>   components and try to re-elect
>   (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
>   [2017-11-25 17:34:18,317] DEBUG [Controller 2]: Controller resigning,
>   broker id 2 (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2017-11-25
>   17:34:18,317] DEBUG [Controller 2]: De-registering
>   IsrChangeNotificationListener (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
>   [2017-11-25 17:34:18,317] INFO [delete-topics-thread-2], Shutting down
>   (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager$DeleteTopicsThread) [2017-11-25
>   17:34:18,317] INFO [delete-topics-thread-2], Stopped 
>   (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager$DeleteTopicsThread) [2017-11-25
>   17:34:18,318] INFO [delete-topics-thread-2], Shutdown completed
>   (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager$DeleteTopicsThread) [2017-11-25
>   17:34:18,318] INFO [Partition state machine on Controller 2]: Stopped
>   partition state machine (kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine)
>   [2017-11-25 17:34:18,318] INFO [Replica state machine on controller
>   2]: Stopped replica state machine
>   (kafka.controller.ReplicaStateMachine) [2017-11-25 17:34:18,318] INFO
>   [Controller-2-to-broker-2-send-thread], Shutting down
>   (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread) [2017-11-25 17:34:18,318] INFO
>   [Controller-2-to-broker-2-send-thread], Stopped 
>   (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread) [2017-11-25 17:34:18,319] INFO
>   [Controller-2-to-broker-2-send-thread], Shutdown completed
>   (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread) [2017-11-25 17:34:18,319] INFO
>   [Controller-2-to-broker-1-send-thread], Shutting down
>   (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread) [2017-11-25 17:34:18,319] INFO
>   [Controller-2-to-broker-1-send-thread], Stopped 
>   (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread) [2017-11-25 17:34:18,319] INFO
>   [Controller-2-to-broker-1-send-thread], Shutdown completed
>   (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread) [2017-11-25 17:34:18,319] INFO
>   [Controller 2]: Broker 2 resigned as the controller
>   (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2017-11-25 17:34:18,353] DEBUG
>   [IsrChangeNotificationListener] Fired!!!
>   (kafka.controller.IsrChangeNotificationListener) [2017-11-25
>   17:34:18,353] DEBUG [IsrChangeNotificationListener] Fired!!!
>   (kafka.controller.IsrChangeNotificationListener) [2017-11-25
>   17:34:18,354] INFO [BrokerChangeListener on Controller 2]: Broker
>   change listener fired for path /brokers/ids with children 1,2
>   (kafka.controller.ReplicaStateMachine$BrokerChangeListener)
>   [2017-11-25 17:34:18,355] DEBUG [DeleteTopicsListener on 2]: Delete
>   topics listener fired for topics  to be deleted
>   (kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$DeleteTopicsListener)
>   [2017-11-25 17:34:18,362] INFO [AddPartitionsListener on 2]: Partition
>   modification triggered {"version":1,"partitions":{"0":[1]}} for path
>   /brokers/topics/ESQ
>   (kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$PartitionModificationsListener)
>   [2017-11-25 17:34:18,368] INFO [AddPartitionsListener on 2]: Partition
>   modification triggered {"version":1,"partitions":{"0":[1]}} for path
>   /brokers/topics/Test1
>   (kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$PartitionModificationsListener)
>   [2017-11-25 17:34:18,369] INFO [AddPartitionsListener on 2]: Partition
>   modification triggered {"version":1,"partitions":{"0":[2]}} for path
>   /brokers/topics/ImageQ
>   (kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$PartitionModificationsListener)
>   [2017-11-25 17:34:18,374] INFO [AddPartitionsListener on 2]: Partition
>   modification triggered
>   {"version":1,"partitions":{"8":[1,2],"4":[1,2],"9":[2,1],"5":[2,1],"6":[1,2],"1":[2,1],"0":[1,2],"2":[1,2],"7":[2,1],"3":[2,1]}}
>   for path /brokers/topics/NMS_NotifyQ
>   (kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$PartitionModificationsListener)
>   [2017-11-25 17:34:18,375] INFO [AddPartitionsListener on 2]: Partition
>   modification triggered {"version":1,"partitions":{"0":[1]}} for path
>   /brokers/topics/TempBinLogReqQ  @